# Make http/https optional in laravel validation

Tags: laravel-4

When I use laravel url validation rules like:-

```
array(
      'name' => 'required|min:3',
      'url' => 'required|url'
)
```

It rejects any url that does not have http:// or https://. However I would like to make it optional.

Answer (score 1):

You can just ignore the url rule. Or you need to prefix your input.

Another way is to set an custom rule.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `url` rule, `http(s)://` is mandatory, because the part that makes a UR**I** a UR**L** is the inclusion of the "access mechanism", which is what `http://` or `ftp://` is for.

You should consider custom rule perhaps or some logic that would add `http://` to validated value if you detect no "access mechanism" part present.